# Raspberry pi and kk2.1 flight control board

Tags: gpio, hardware

I want to establish communication between a raspberry pi and a flight control board (specifically this [one](https://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__49254__Hobbyking_KK2_1_Multi_rotor_LCD_Flight_Control_Board_With_6050MPU_And_Atmel_644PA.html?gclid=COm02Lac0bwCFUQUwwodsyEAnQ)).

This is for a quadcopter project. Now I know there projects out there where the pi is the flight controller, but I want to offload this task.

Not quite sure where to begin here, would appreciate any assistance! I recall seeing a blog post integrating an arduino with the kk2.1 board, and I wouldn't mind using another board inbetween if that will make it easier.

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert on this, but you should be able to directly connect the pins on the controller board to the Pi GPIO.

You should not need an Arduino in between as the board is already technically an Arduino, all you need to do is pass the signals through Serial/Whatever the board supports.

Alternatively, if you can access the firmware you could buy an IC programmer by someone like Atmel and use that to reprogram the chip with input support from the Pi.

[image: Raspberry Pi GPIO]

Comment: Thanks. I know the kk2.1 board has SDA and SCL output channels. But I'm not quite sure on how to program with them. And will these two channels be enough? I will play around :)

Comment: You should be OK, again, I am not too sure of the specifics but let us know.